# Create a CA Layer dynamically between two CA Layer

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, core-animation, calayer

My view have multiple CA layers arranged like UITableView Cells. I have created the layer dynamically one after other in a top down order.
But I want to create a layer between the two layers, I want to create the layer between two layers when I pinch out between two layers. How can i do that.
I am new to this, so any help or direction to something closer would be great.
...

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging alot here and there, I got my answer from an Example [here](https://github.com/MassiveHealth/Opaque).
It not just gave me my answer, I actually learned some new stuff about CALayer and core animation, some of its details are [here](http://blog.massivehealth.com/post/18563684407/clear)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the *CALayer* methods

```
- (void)insertSublayer:(CALayer *)aLayer atIndex:(unsigned)index
- (void)insertSublayer:(CALayer *)aLayer below:(CALayer *)sublayer
- (void)insertSublayer:(CALayer *)aLayer above:(CALayer *)sublayer
```

to insert a new layer at a specific point in the sublayers array.

Answer (score 0):

dont know if I get it.. but when you create the layers, make sure they are in the same layer tree (sublayers (or subsublayers) of the same layer)

so l1 has l2 has l3

then the zorder would be there already

---

now you have l_parent has {l1 and l2 and l3 and l4} ... lx are siblings

TODO:
**set the zindex of the layers**